# appending text to a frame

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working off code that was used by my instructor in an info design class, and I'm trying to make something where each frame shows the "time", "emotion", and "Heartbeat".

The "time", "emotion" are already in the code and works, but I'm having trouble adding "Heartbeat". I added the heartbeat data into the json file:

```
 [{
    "img": "00.01.39.jpg",
    "time": "0:01:39",
    "emotion": "Surprise",
    "heartbeat": "98"
},
```

Now here's the problem, can I add it to show on the frame by just adding it into this part?:

//Creates the text on each frame with the timecode and the emotion attached to that frame

```
frames.append("p")
    .attr("class", "frame-time")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.time
    })
    .append("span")
    .attr("class", "frame-emotion")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.emotion
    });
```

I tried adding this after the emotion, but it didn't work:

```
 .append("span")
 .attr("class","frame-heartbeat")
 .text(function(d){return d.heartbeat})
```

I also tried this:

```
 .append("span")
 .attr("class","frame-emotion")
 .text(function(d){return d.emotion+d.heartbeat});
```

But I ended up with "SURPRISE98" - with no space in-between. I'd ALSObe happy with it showing up as "SURPRISE 98BPM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the space to the generated string:

```
 .append("span")
.attr("class","frame-emotion")
.text(function(d) { return d.emotion + " " + d.heartbeat + "BPM"; });
```

If you want to add it as a frame on its own, append it to `frames`:

```
frames.append("p")
  .attr("class", "frame-heartbeat")
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.heartbeat;
  });
```